# When updating app from Google Play will the app data be deleted?

Tags: game-maker, savegame, google-play

My question is pretty simple.

I developed a game, uploaded it on the store. In order to keep player level record and UI prefs it writes an ini file.

When the next update is up on the store and the users will update will they lose their progress? Will the file be deleted?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When updating the app, all the saved data will remain the same. This includes local files you write to, which you seem to be using.